# how to import Microsoft Face API: Android Client Library & Sample into android studio

Tags: android, face-api

I need to work on microsoft cognitive service FACE API, i have downloaded the code from github, but i am unable to import the code into my android and test it.
Could some one help me in importing the code into my android studio

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this dependency in build.gradle file

dependencies {

...
compile 'com.microsoft.projectoxford:face:1.1.0'
}

block.